# Having issues putting multiple items in a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get three items in a single tableview cell just like the picture.

I want the app to look exactly like the picture.

[Image(CLICK ME) What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE5E3.jpg)

I have tried to do this a million different way but cant seem to figure out the correct way to do it, the app completely crash right now.

Need some help as i am a beginner to swift, i am still learning but for some reason this has been a challenge.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items:[Product]? = []

    // VIEW LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.isModalInPresentation = true
        }

        getData()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        getData()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        storeData()
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    // ADD ITEMS
    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Product Information", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (itemTextField) in
            itemTextField.placeholder = "Item"
        }
        alert.addTextField { (priceTextField) in
            priceTextField.placeholder = "Price"
        }

        alert.addTextField { (salePriceTextField) in
            salePriceTextField.placeholder = "Sale Price"
        }

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (_) in
            let item = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
            let price = alert.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
            let salesPrice = alert.textFields?[2].text ?? ""

            let product = Product(item: item, price: price, salesPrice: salesPrice)
            self.addProduct(product)
        }

        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true)
        storeData()

    }

    func addProduct(_ product: Product) {
        let index = 0
        items?.insert(product, at: index)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        storeData()
    }

    //STORE DATA
    func storeData() {
        UserDefaultUtil.saveData(products: items)
    }

    func getData() {
        items = UserDefaultUtil.loadProducts()

    }

}

//EXTENSION
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let product = items![indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(product.item!) \(product.price) \(product.salesPrice)"

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.92, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        items?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        storeData()
    }
}

class UserDefaultUtil {

    private static let Key = "savedData"

    private static func archivePeople(people : [Product]) -> NSData {

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people as NSArray) as NSData
    }

    static func loadProducts() -> [Product]? {

        if let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Key) as? Data {

            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: unarchivedObject as Data) as? [Product]
        }

        return nil
    }

    static func saveData(products : [Product]?) {
        let archivedObject = archivePeople(people: products!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedObject, forKey: Key)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

}

class Product: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var item: String?
    var price: String?
    var salesPrice: String?

    required init(item:String, price:String, salesPrice: String) {
        self.item = item
        self.price = price
        self.salesPrice = salesPrice
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.item = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "item") as? String
        self.price = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "price") as? String
        self.salesPrice = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "salesPrice") as? String
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(item, forKey: "item")
        aCoder.encode(price, forKey: "price")
        aCoder.encode(salesPrice, forKey: "salesPrice")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items = [Product]()

    // VIEW LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.isModalInPresentation = true
        }

        getData()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        getData()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        storeData()
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    // ADD ITEMS
    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Product Information", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (itemTextField) -> Void in
                   itemTextField.placeholder = "Item"
        })
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (priceTextField) -> Void in
                   priceTextField.placeholder = "Price"
        })
       alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (salePriceTextField) -> Void in
                salePriceTextField.placeholder = "Sale Price"
       })



        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            let item = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
            let price = alert.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
            let salesPrice = alert.textFields?[2].text ?? ""

            let product = Product(item: item, price: price, salesPrice: salesPrice)
           self.addProduct(product)
        })

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        storeData()

    }

    func addProduct(_ product: Product) {
        items.append(product)
        tableView.reloadData()
        storeData()
    }

    //STORE DATA
    func storeData() {
        UserDefaultUtil.saveData(products: items)
    }

    func getData() {
         if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "savedData"), let unarchivedObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Product] {
            items = unarchivedObject
        }
    }

}

//EXTENSION
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let product = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(product.item!) \(product.price) \(product.salesPrice)"

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.92, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        storeData()
    }
}

class UserDefaultUtil {

    private static let Key = "savedData"

    private static func archivePeople(people : [Product]) -> NSData {

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people as NSArray) as NSData
    }


    static func saveData(products : [Product]?) {
        let archivedObject = archivePeople(people: products!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedObject, forKey: Key)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

}

class Product: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var item: String?
    var price: String?
    var salesPrice: String?

   required init(item:String, price:String, salesPrice: String) {
        self.item = item
        self.price = price
        self.salesPrice = salesPrice
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.item = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "item") as? String
        self.price = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "price") as? String
        self.salesPrice = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "salesPrice") as? String
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(item, forKey: "item")
        aCoder.encode(price, forKey: "price")
        aCoder.encode(salesPrice, forKey: "salesPrice")
    }
}
```

Comment: i get four errors. The errors are "Value of type '[Product]?' has no member 'append' ", " Value of optional type '[Product]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'count' of wrapped base type '[Product]' ", " Value of optional type '[Product]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[Product]' ", " Value of type '[Product]?' has no member 'remove' "  @Tanjima Kothiya

Comment: i also get , " 'archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead ", " 'unarchiveObject(with:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead "   @Tanjima Kothiya

Comment: i update my code ,i have not any error  in my code @MG3

Comment: it prints out perfectly thank you so much, now how would i get more spacing in between? right now it prints very close to eachother?

Comment: @MG3 you talk to alert TextField close to eachother

Comment: so if i type in shoes, $20.00, $30.00 how do i calculate the profit and show it in another label? @Tanjima Kothiya

Answer (score 0):

> Total Profit Calculate

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items = [Product]()

    // VIEW LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.isModalInPresentation = true
        }

        getData()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        getData()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        storeData()
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    // ADD ITEMS
    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Product Information", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (itemTextField) -> Void in
                   itemTextField.placeholder = "Item"
        })
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (priceTextField) -> Void in
                   priceTextField.placeholder = "Price"
        })
       alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (salePriceTextField) -> Void in
                salePriceTextField.placeholder = "Sale Price"
       })



        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            let item = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
            let price = alert.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
            let salesPrice = alert.textFields?[2].text ?? ""


            let profit = Double(salesPrice)! - Double(price)!
            let  TotalProfit = profit


            let product = Product(item: item, price: price, salesPrice: salesPrice, TotalProfit: TotalProfit)
           self.addProduct(product)
        })

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        storeData()

    }

    func addProduct(_ product: Product) {
        items.append(product)
        tableView.reloadData()
        storeData()
    }

    //STORE DATA
    func storeData() {
        UserDefaultUtil.saveData(products: items)
    }

    func getData() {
         if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "savedData"), let unarchivedObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Product] {
            items = unarchivedObject
        }
    }

}

//EXTENSION
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let product = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(product.item!) \(String(describing: product.price)) \(String(describing: product.salesPrice))"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Total Profit \(product.TotalProfit)"
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.92, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        storeData()
    }

}

class UserDefaultUtil {

    private static let Key = "savedData"

    private static func archivePeople(people : [Product]) -> NSData {

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people as NSArray) as NSData
    }


    static func saveData(products : [Product]?) {
        let archivedObject = archivePeople(people: products!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedObject, forKey: Key)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

}

class Product: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var item: String?
    var price: String?
    var salesPrice: String?
    var TotalProfit: Double?

    init(item:String, price:String, salesPrice: String ,TotalProfit: Double ) {
        self.item = item
        self.price = price
        self.salesPrice = salesPrice
        self.TotalProfit = TotalProfit
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.item = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "item") as? String
        self.price = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "price") as? String
        self.salesPrice = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "salesPrice") as? String
        self.TotalProfit = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "TotalProfit") as? Double
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(item, forKey: "item")
        aCoder.encode(price, forKey: "price")
        aCoder.encode(salesPrice, forKey: "salesPrice")
        aCoder.encode(TotalProfit, forKey: "TotalProfit")
    }
}
```